# Make delayed job run at specific date time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I want to send some emails through `delayed_job`

However, I want to send them before and after an event.

My concern is if this will actually work:

```
def one_week_before_run
  AtendeeMailer.delay(run_at: '8th October 2016'.to_datetime).mudrun_about_to_start(self)
end

def thank_you_note
  AtendeeMailer.delay(run_at: '18th October 2016'.to_datetime.end_of_day).thank_you(self)
end
```

or should I choose another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delayed job picks a job to execute only if the run_at <= current time. Refer DJ's query to pick job

```
SELECT `delayed_jobs`.* FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE ((run_at <= '2016-09-27 00:49:59' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2016-09-27 00:24:59') OR locked_by = 'host:Madhubalans-Air pid:74314') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

Your code is setting run_at to 2016-10-18 00:00:00 and 2016-10-18 23:59:59.
So your code will work as per your expectation :)