# Sending Email with Delayed_Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have what I think is a working setup to send emails via `Delayed_Job`.  However, I haven't received my test email and it isn't practical to wait for more to happen with a delay of days.  I need to figure out:

1. What's wrong that's causing the email not to send.
2. How to test it without waiting days at a time.

I'm new to `Delayed_Job`, so pardon the newbie mistakes.

Here's the model that includes the `send_reminder_emails` method.  They were fully functional without the `.delay(run_at: self.mail_date)` bit, so at least I know that much works:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :create_mail_date
  after_save :send_reminder_emails
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  def create_mail_date
    @schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new(self.date)
    case self.repeating
    when "Weekly"
        @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
            IceCube::Rule.weekly
        )
    when "Monthly"
        @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
            IceCube::Rule.monthly.day_of_month(self.date.mon)
        )
    when "Yearly"
        @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
            IceCube::Rule.yearly.day_of_year(self.date.yday)
        )
    end
    if self.repeating
        self.date = @schedule.next_occurrence(Time.now)
    end
    self.mail_date = self.date - 7.days
  end

  private

  def send_reminder_emails
      if self.reminder
         ReminderMailer.delay(run_at: self.mail_date).reminder_send(self.user, self).deliver_now
         self.create_mail_date
     end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :send_reminder_emails

end
```

The references to `schedule` are via the `Ice_Cube` gem and all of the date stuff has been tested via my console and is working.  Here is my `reminder_mailer.rb`:

```
class ReminderMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "man@manlyartofbbq.com"

  def reminder_send(user, reminder)
    @user = user
    @reminder = reminder

    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Reminder! #{reminder.name} is fast approaching!")
  end
end
```

I installed `Delayed_Job` step by step from their readme for Rails 4.  Any help getting the delayed part of this mailer ironed out is appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you run `Delayed::Job.all` in rails console.

Comment: @Dinesh, I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Delayed
from (pry):12:in `__pry__'`  I feel like that's a bad sign.

Comment: is there a git repo for this?

Comment: A possibility: Last time I looked at DelayedJob, it was designed to detect when mailer arguments are ActiveRecord instances and, in that case, save in the job queue not the object but the id field of the object. When the job is ready to run, it uses the id for a lookup. I guess this is an optimization. However, _if you use an unsaved ActiveRecord as an argument, the lookup fails, the task emits a log record and dies_. Here, e.g. if `IceCube::Schedule` is an ActiveRecord subclass, that's likely to be what's happening.

Comment: @Gene, anything to do with IceCube is not touched by the DelayedJob processes (it's in other unrelated methods).  The only thing the DelayedJob is relying on is a date saved in the database.

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII, [here](https://github.com/LizBayardelle/manly-art-bbq)'s the git repo.

Comment: @Liz That's as may be, but looking at your reminders_controller, I don't see anywhere that the reminder date and mail_date fields are saved. This may well affect the job. For testing, why don't you try running with no run_at param, so the job runs asynchronously but without the wait. What in the delayed job log? That was the key info source for debugging my similar problem.

Comment: Hi. Can you please remove the 'deliver_now'  from '       ReminderMailer.delay(run_at: self.mail_date).reminder_send(self.user, self).deliver_now' and check

Comment: @Liz Would you like to go with active job for sending mails

Comment: @balakarthik, anything that allows me to schedule an email to be sent on a later date.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Active Job for sending mails by scheduling the job at a particular time.

Active Job is a framework for declaring jobs and making them run on a variety of queuing backends. These jobs can be everything from regularly scheduled clean-ups, to billing charges, to mailings. Anything that can be chopped up into small units of work and run in parallel, really.

For enqueuing and executing jobs in production you need to set up a queuing backend, that is to say you need to decide for a 3rd-party queuing library that Rails should use. Rails itself only provides an in-process queuing system, which only keeps the jobs in RAM. If the process crashes or the machine is reset, then all outstanding jobs are lost with the default async back-end. This may be fine for smaller apps or non-critical jobs, but most production apps will need to pick a persistent backend.

Active Job has built-in adapters for multiple queuing backends (Sidekiq, Resque, Delayed Job and others). To get an up-to-date list of the adapters see the API Documentation for [ActiveJob::QueueAdapters.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html)

Once after configuring the queuing adapters, then create Job for sending mails

```
class RemainderMailerJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user, remainder)
   ReminderMailer.reminder_send(user, reminder).deliver
  end
end
```

For sending the mail on a specific time you need to enqueue the job and make it perform at a specific time. If you need to send mail 7 days from now then call this piece of code where ever you need.

```
RemainderMailerJob.set(wait: 1.week).perform_later(user, remainder)
```

Now this Job will execute after 1 week, which in turn calls the mailer at that time, so your mails will be sent on the specific day.

IF you knew the specific Date Time then you can use

```
RemainderMailerJob.set(wait_untill: <Specific date>).perform_later(user, remainder)
```

If you have any doubts regarding the active job kindly refer [Active Job Basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)

Comment: I appreciate your incredibly thorough response. The problem is that I'm trying to get it to send at a date determined by the database, not by when the job is queued. I can't use something like 'wait: 1.week' because it could be a week or a month or a day. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Liz You can use `GuestsCleanupJob.set(wait_until: <A specific date>).perform_later(guest)`

Comment: @Liz I have made changes in the answer, Look at it.

Comment: Even with this addition (which is awesome), I still get a `run_at: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 23:37:08 UTC +00:00,` (it shows the `run_at` date in delayed job as the time saved, not the `mail_date` specified when I called `RemainderMailerJob.set(wait_until: self.mail_date).perform_later(user, remainder)` in my method.

Comment: @Liz I have tested it with a sample job using `RemainderMailerJob.set(wait_until: 3.days.from_now).perform_later(user, remainder)` and the result i have got is `#<RemainderMailerJob:0x007fe37c165c08 @arguments=[157, 0], @job_id="6543fe81-4ef5-4228-b875-4508dfd9b77e", @queue_name="default", @priority=nil, @provider_job_id="90a61e2d98520dfec0473cd3", @scheduled_at=1477552788.4407418>` where the scheduled_at contains the time on which the job scheduled to run. If possible can you try this process in console and post the result as a comment

Comment: I tried that as a test and the `run_at` date is still the date when it was saved.  Where did you get that result?  I've been looking at `Delayed::Job.last` in the console, but the results come out in a different format than the one you posted.

Comment: @Liz first of all this is not delayed job this is active job. Pls refer the link that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

When you send mails using delayed job, there is no need to add 'deliver' or 'deliver_now' when initializing the delayed_job for mailer. So

```
ReminderMailer.delay(run_at: self.mail_date).reminder_send(self.user, self)
```

will itself work.

Convert your 'self.mail_date' to also include the time at which you want to send the mail. Passing only date will not work. Basically the run_at should specify both date and time.

Please check the 'delayed_job' github link under the heading "Rails 3 Mailers"
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: Thanks for catching this oversight.  The items now come up in my console when I do `Delayed::Job.all`.  However, the `run_at` is still whatever time the item goes into the queue, not the `mail_date` from the database.  Thoughts?

Comment: the run_at parameter is used to pass in 'Time' and not 'Date'. A delayed job can never be scheduled for a date, but only for time. I guess, you can run the delayed job only for records whose date is the current date when the job is run. And pass the time for execution in the 'run_at' param. hope this helps. An upvote for my answer will be appreciated. :)

Comment: According to questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713242/make-delayed-job-run-at-specific-date-time) it seems like it should be possible...

Comment: I apologize my friend. That's right. I just want to make sure whether the "self.mail_date" is a date type? or a datetime type?. Passing in a date with time should work. You can make a try I guess.

Comment: Cool. Please try and if that works, please accept my answer too. :) I have added the new change too in the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will definitely accept your answer, I just want to figure it out first.  Even with the column type for `mail_date` changed to `datetime` the `run_at` is still whenever the delayed job was entered, even though it lists the correct `mail_date` in the delayed job handler.  Argh!

Comment: ok, you changed the column to datetime. And I guess the mailer is moved to the delayed job at the same time, when the record is created, is'nt? Can you check the records in db(mail_date), what does it store? Is it not storing the same time? Or are you explicitly passing a different time, when the record is created?. Just check whether the run_at is the same as the database entry. If so then it means you will have to explicitly pass the time you want the delayed job to run. Else it will store the time at which the mail_date was saved to database.

Comment: For some reason, even though the column type for `date` and `mail_date` is `datetime`, they are only showing the date in the console (e.g. ` mail_date: Fri, 04 Nov 2016`).  Does this mean it's somehow only saving the date?  I changed the view forms to `<%= f.datetime_field :date, class: "form-control" %>` (instead of a `f.date_field`) and resaved the event in question, but still it only saves the date?  How is this possible?

Comment: I would prefer to use datetime_select helper inside your forms. <%= f.datetime_select :mail_date %>. This will save the correct date and time, which are selected from the views. Now check the data in console, by creating a new record or editing an existing record.

Comment: Even with the `datetime_select` it still saves as `date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016`!

Comment: In create_mail_date method in your model, there is a line of code, self.mail_date = self.date - 7.days. I guess something goes wrong with self.date which you use to assign value to mail_date. Can you print it out and check what values the calculation gives you. I guess mail_date is assigned only date. Please check

Comment: I figured out (via [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186914/rails-console-showing-date-only-for-datetime-column) auxilliary post) that it was the column name sabotaging my `date` column from the `datetime` type.  Now the `date` column (now named `event_date`) displays a `datetime` format.  To answer your most recent comment, the `mail_date` does display 7 days prior to the `event_date` in the console.

Comment: So everything works fine now? Or there are still issues?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the original issue (where the Delayed Job `run_at` date is whenever the reminder is saved, regardless of the `mail_date` still persists.

Comment: why do you set time in the method @schedule.next_occurrence(Time.now). You are setting the current time?

Comment: That's part of the `[ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube)` gem's lexicon.  `schedule.next_occurrence(from_time)` refers to the next time a repeating event happens after the time in the parentheses.

Comment: Should it not be the time from event_date? Or should it be from the current time?

Comment: Basically it's making sure the `event_date` isn't in the past for repeating events, by setting it to the *next* occurrence of the event.  Either way, the dates in the console are right for each event, they're just not reflecting in the Delayed Job `run_at` date.

Comment: one final check. can you please print out what is the value of mail_date inside the send_reminder_emails method? Do that have date and time in it?

Comment: before the if self.reminder? just put in as puts self.mail_date and tell me what comes in your logs.

Comment: Still couldn't find it in my server log after that, but in the server log the object passed to Delayed Job still said `mail_date: &7 2016-11-04 17:58:00.000000000`.

Comment: Am really sorry @liz. Am out of suggestions now. I guess with all these things correct, it should be working by now.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when attribute protection is misconfigured. (Usually on legacy apps that left some kludge in when upgrading rails version.)

See if you're able to set the field from the console: `Delayed::Job.new(run_at: 1.year.from_now)`. If not, that's the culprit and you'll need to track down the cause in your app.

If it works, then we still need to verify whether this is an app problem or a DJ bug. Make a new minimal rails app with just a delayed_job table and try to reproduce this. If you can't then there's something else odd in your app.