# Rails Console Showing Date Only for Datetime Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two columns in my `Reminders` model (`date` and `mail_date`) which have the column type `datetime`, as you can see in my `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "reminders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.boolean  "reminder",      default: false
    t.string   "repeating"
    t.boolean  "approved"
    t.boolean  "gift",          default: false
    t.boolean  "gift_help",     default: false
    t.string   "occasion_type", default: "Other"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "slug"
    t.datetime "mail_date"
  end
```

However, in my `console`, they are only shown as dates:

```
[33] pry(main)> Reminder.where(name: "Mentor Call")
  Reminder Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "reminders".* FROM "reminders" WHERE "reminders"."name" = ?  [["name", "Mentor Call"]]
=> [#<Reminder:0x007fe32b13f090
  id: 8,
  name: "Mentor Call",
  date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016,
  reminder: true,
  repeating: "Weekly",
  approved: nil,
  gift: false,
  gift_help: false,
  occasion_type: "Other",
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 01:59:57 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 23:47:16 UTC +00:00,
  slug: "mentor-call",
  mail_date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016>]
```

I know the `datetime` data is being saved, because it displays on my view page, where this...

```
October 27, 2016 07:00  Mentor Call     ... 2016-10-27 07:00:00 UTC
```

...is generated from this erb:

```
<% @reminders.each do |o| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= o.date.try(:to_formatted_s, :long) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to reminder_path(o), style: "color: black" do %>
          <strong><%= o.name %></strong>
        <% end %>
        ...
      <td>
        <% if o.reminder %>
          <%= o.mail_date.try(:to_formatted_s, "%m/%d/%Y") %>
        <% else %>
          None, you're on your own.
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to create a `mailer` that sends out on `mail_date`, but am having trouble (I think) due to this `datetime` vs `date` issue.  Can anyone straighten me out?

Comment: What happens if you call the `date` column something else, such as `remind_on`?

Comment: @mysmallidea, you live up to your username.  That totally fixed it.  If you write it up as an answer I will happily select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the name of the `date` column is running afoul of Rails' or Ruby's [reserved words](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_reserved_words). Change the name of the `date` column to something else, like `remind_at`, and that should do the trick:

```
create_table "reminders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "remind_at"
  t.boolean  "reminder",      default: false
  # ...
end
```

Comment: As a general convention, I like to use descriptive names ending with "_on" for dates and "_at" for datetimes. So instead of `mail_date` I would use `mailed_at`. If I just wanted the date (no time) I would call it `mailed_on`. To me this reads better and helps to inform the expected return value when I (or other developers) read the source code months or years from now.